# volley imageloader imagelistener just show the the errorImageResId

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, imageloader

For fetching images and showing them in a recycler view I used volley imageloader,

Pic_class.java

```
    public class Pic_class {
    //Data Variables
    private String url;
    private String name;

    //Getters and Setters
    public String geturl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void seturl(String imageUrl) {
        this.url = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

CardAdapter.java

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //Imageloader to load image
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;

    //List to store all superheroes
    List<Pic_class> superHeroes;

    //Constructor of this class
    public CardAdapter(List<Pic_class> superHeroes, Context context){
        super();
        //Getting all superheroes
        this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.pic_recycler, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //Getting the particular item from the list
        Pic_class superHero =  superHeroes.get(position);


        Log.i("superHero(position)",superHero.geturl());


        //Loading image from url
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(superHero.geturl(),
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                        holder.imageView,
                        R.drawable.exit,
                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        Log.i("imageLoader",imageLoader.toString());

        //Showing data on the views
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(superHero.geturl(), imageLoader);
        holder.textViewName.setText(superHero.getName());
        //holder.textViewPublisher.setText(superHero.getPublisher());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return superHeroes.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        //Views
        public NetworkImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewName;
       // public TextView textViewPublisher;

        //Initializing Views
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
           // textViewPublisher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublisher);
        }
    }
}
```

Last_pics.java

```
    public class Last_pics extends Fragment /*implements RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener*/{


    //Data URL
    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://10.0.3.2:90/android/pic_list.php?page=";
    //JSON TAGS
    public static final String TAG_TEN = "ten";
    public static final String TAG_URL = "url";

    //Creating a List of superheroes
    private List<Pic_class> listSuperHeroes;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    //Volley Request Queue
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    //The request counter to send ?page=1, ?page=2  requests
    private int requestCount = 1;


    LinearLayout ll;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /** Inflating the layout for this fragment **/
        ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.last_pics, container, false);

        //Initializing Views
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) ll.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        //Initializing our superheroes list
        listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        //Calling method to get data to fetch data
        getData();

        //Adding an scroll change listener to recyclerview
//        recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);

        //initializing our adapter
        adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes, getActivity());

        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return ll;
    }


    //Request to get json from server we are passing an integer here
    //This integer will used to specify the page number for the request ?page = requestcount
    //This method would return a JsonArrayRequest that will be added to the request queue
    private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
        //Initializing ProgressBar
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) ll.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        //Displaying Progressbar
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        //JsonArrayRequest of volley
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                       parseData(response);
                        //Hiding the progressbar
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        //Returning the request
        return jsonArrayRequest;
    }


    //This method will get data from the web api
    private void getData() {
        //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
        requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
        //Incrementing the request counter
        requestCount++;
    }


    //This method will parse json data
    private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            //Creating the superhero object
            Pic_class superHero = new Pic_class();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                //Getting json
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding data to the superhero object
                superHero.seturl(json.getString(TAG_URL));
                superHero.setName(json.getString(TAG_TEN));

                Log.i("dooghaie",superHero.getName()+superHero.geturl());
                //superHero.setPublisher(json.getString(Config.TAG_PUBLISHER));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Adding the superhero object to the list
            listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);
        }

        //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //This method would check that the recyclerview scroll has reached the bottom or not
    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

But in run, in emulator, in the recyclerview, just there are android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert in imageviews
instead of images from database.
What is wrong? Why it doesn't show images from database?